# Apache2, re-direct blank.example.com to example.com/blank/blank

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues with this re-direct. I've tried the .htaccess method with RewriteRule and RewriteCond, as well as the VirtualDirectory method. Here's what I've tried for VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blank.example.com
    Redirect permanent / "http://example.com/blank/blank"

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /the/doc/root

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

and this for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blank.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blank/blank [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure if it's needed or not, but blank.example.com is also pointed to localhost in /etc/hosts

Any tips on what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you trying to changing the URL to use the main domain with subfolders and NOT show the subdomain? Or are you wanting to use the subdomain in the browser and server files from the sub folder?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make this like a URL shortener. So I don't really care if it shows the full URL that it's redirecting to, but users need to be able to click on the shorter link and get to that redirected URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things.

If you are wanting to just have a `subdomain` with it's own document root then your vhost needs to look like this. Then there is no need to redirect.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blank.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/blank/blank
    <Directory /path/to/blank/blank>
      #enable .htaccess for this subdomain
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**If you are truly wanting to redirect your subdomain to the main domain.**

*Then remove this first vhost*. it's not needed at all.

```
 #This virtualhost is not needed
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blank.example.com
    Redirect permanent / "http://example.com/blank/blank"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then on your main VirtualHost add a server alias like so

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias blank.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /the/doc/root

<Directory /the/doc/root>
    #enable .htaccess for this main domain
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Then for your .htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blank\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blank/blank/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Restart Apache after all config file changes.

Comment: This is getting me in the right direction, but it just takes me to the root of example.com, instead of example.com/blank/blank

Comment: which part did you do of my answer?

Comment: The second part, so I added an alias and tried the RewriteCond